# ROS Answers SE migration: notice wall

Tags: ros, avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i am trying to program my robot so that he drives straight ahead until he is close to a wall or so, and then he should turn right or so... just drive ahead in a other way.
So my question is, if i get my data from my sensors and make a map out of them, is there any way how i can use that information,or are there some packages at ros.org, to notice wehen i am to close to a wall? I am using a Hokuyu laser

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38723/notice-wall/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

you better start reading navigation [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

if you need something that simple you can write your own code. just subscribe your laser scan messages, put  a threshold value (i.e 50 cm close to an object ) then send velocity commands or position commands to your robot's motor drivers. if you are not familiar with ros, you can start from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials)

hope this helps you out

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2